# Aliasing `rm` to create a CLI "recycle bin"

Tags: rm, alias

When we do

```
mv /root/file /root/folder/
```

It moves `/root/file` to `/root/folder`

I want to do the same thing, but I want to reverse the order of how `mv` perceives the arguments

I want to declare an **alias (not function)** like

```
alias rm="mv /root/folder"
```

So, when I would do

`rm /root/file`

it would move that particular file to the `/root/folder`

---

*Why, I don't want to use a function?*

Because I cannot name the function `rm()` as the keyword `rm` already exists.

I want to be able to use the keyword `rm` because it's a regular habit for all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias rm="mv -t /root/folder"` will do that if you have a `mv` that supports the nonstandard `-t` option.
See [mv(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) for more options (you'll probably want `--no-clobber` / `--interactive` too).

If you want a POSIX solution, you can absolutely work around the basic `rm` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html#top) with a function named `rm`:

```
rm() {  mv "$@" /root/folder;  } # a start
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I think this is a bad idea. If you want to use a *trash* or *recycle bin* on the command line, install `trash-cli`.

Why I think it is a bad idea:

- What happens when you want to use `rm` - the exiting, remove files or directories application?
- What happens when you move a file with a file name that matches a file already in `/root/folder`?

---

It's worth noting that the [author of `trash-cli` also thinks this aliasing is a bad idea](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli#can-i-alias-rm-to-trash-put), after some experience with it:

> **Can I alias rm to trash-put?**
>
> You can but you shouldn't. In the early days I thought it was a good idea to do that but now I changed my mind.
>
> ...

And, Andrea [recommends an alternative approach](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli#but-sometimes-i-forget-to-use-trash-put-really-cant-i):

> You could alias rm to something that will remind you to not use it:
>
> ```
> alias rm='echo "This is not the command you are looking for."; false'
> ```

Comment: Another reason not to re-use `rm` is when you use other machines, you will assume it's the "safe recycle bin" version.