# How to make files deleted from a mounted partion go to the "recycle bin" on CentOS 7

Tags: centos

I'd like to know how can i set a mounted partition to send deleted files from main directory to the "recycle bin" on CentOS 7. They all are removed directly.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452496/create-a-recycle-bin-feature-without-using-functions and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379138/aliasing-rm-to-create-a-cli-recycle-bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends completely on the method of deletion. If you are issuing `rm -rf` on this secondary mounted partition you will never get those files back without using a file system that allows you to restore from a previous snapshot or you have backups.

You can however use `trash-cli` or create an alias like described in the related answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452496/create-a-recycle-bin-feature-without-using-functions) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379138/aliasing-rm-to-create-a-cli-recycle-bin) to delete things from the command line and place them in a "recycle bin". If you use a graphical file manager like Nautilus or Dolphin, things deleted from mounted partitions typically go to a "recycle bin" by default.

Install `trash-cli` using `yum install trash-cli`

Delete a file by issuing `trash-put /path/to/file`

Use `trash-list` to see what is in the trash currently and use `trash-restore` to restore the deleted file. And to empty the trash you simply issue `trash-empty`. Using `trash-empty 30` clears out all files that have been in trash for 30 days or longer.

Alternatively you can add an alias to your `.bashrc` that you will use instead of `rm` that [user Kusalananda does in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452497/276845).

> ```
> alias trash='mkdir -p "$HOME/.trash" && mv -b -t "$HOME/.trash"'
> ```